# Using `lapply` to rename selected columns in list

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to understand how to create iteration within a Lapply function and am facing issues with trying to rename columns in a list. Please see the reproducible example below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(fruit=c("apple", "Orange", "Pear"), location = c("Japan", "China", "Nigeria"), price = c(32,53,12))
df2 <- data.frame(grocery = c("Durian", "Apple", "Watermelon"), 
                  place=c("Korea", "Japan", "Malaysia"), 
                  name = c("Mark", "John", "Tammy"), 
                  favourite.food = c("Apple", "ORANGE", "Cakes"), 
                  invoice = c("XD1", "XD2", "XD3"))
df3 <- data.frame(address=c("address1", "address2", "address3"), location = c("USA", "UK", "China"))

allobj <- ls()[sapply(ls(),function(t) is.data.frame(get(t)))]
templist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

> With a simple for loop, I am able to rename the column names in each dataframe

```
for (i in seq_along(templist)){
  colnames(templist[[i]]) <- c(paste0("From ", allobj[1]) , paste0("From ", allobj[i+1])) #will change the column name of each dataframe in a list in seq
}
```

> However with lapply, I am unable to change column 2 of each dataframe. Could someone point out to me my error? Thank you!

```
lapply(seq_along(templist), function(x) {
  i <- seq_along(templist)
  names(x)[2] <- allobj[i]
  x
})
```

**Expected Output**

```
[[1]]
   fruit     df1     price
1  apple    Japan    32
2 Orange    China    53
3   Pear  Nigeria    12

[[2]]
     grocery    df2    name favourite.food invoice
1     Durian    Korea  Mark          Apple     XD1
2      Apple    Japan  John         ORANGE     XD2
3 Watermelon Malaysia Tammy          Cakes     XD3

[[3]]
   address     df3
1 address1      USA
2 address2       UK
3 address3    China
```

Comment: Hmm its different as I'm trying to understand how you iterate within a lapply, i.e. as shown by the `i <- seq_along(templist)`

Comment: just updated the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest to use `mapply` instead

```
mapply(function(x, y) {names(x)[2] <- y; x}, templist, allobj)

#[[1]]
#   fruit     df1 price
#1  apple   Japan    32
#2 Orange   China    53
#3   Pear Nigeria    12

#[[2]]
#     grocery      df2  name favourite.food invoice
#1     Durian    Korea  Mark          Apple     XD1
#2      Apple    Japan  John         ORANGE     XD2
#3  Watermelon Malaysia Tammy         Cakes     XD3

#[[3]]
#   address   df3
#1 address1   USA
#2 address2    UK
#3 address3 China
```

---

If you want to use `lapply` you could use `x` as the index to subset both `templist` as well as `allobj` since for 1st list we want name from 1st value of `allobj`, for 2nd list we want 2nd value of `allobj` and so on.

```
lapply(seq_along(templist), function(x) {
   names(templist[[x]])[2] <- allobj[x]
   templist[[x]]
 })
```

Comment: am i right to say that `templist` is assigned to x and `allobj` is assigned to y? Thank you for sharing the lapply example with iteration!! (:

Comment: @Javier yes, with `mapply` it takes 1st list from `templist` and 1st value from `allobj` and assign the names. In the next iteration it takes second list from `templist`and 2nd value from `allobj` and so on.